# Get email from facebook respond Could not get resource

Tags: facebook, hello.js

I use hello for oauth with facebook.

Login is ok, but no data is returned by Facebook. The message is :

> Whoops! Could not get resource

```
hello.init({
       xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    },{ scope: 'email', redirect_uri: RacineSite() });


    hello(type).login({ scope: 'email' });

    hello.on('auth.login', function (auth) {
        if (type == auth.network) {
            hello(type).api('me').then(function (json) {
                alert('Your name is ' + json.email);
            }, function (e) {
                alert('Whoops! ' + e.error.message);
            });
        }
    });
```

if type = google, its work fine, but with facebook, no email is returned

Comment: you should always add the complete error object, not just the message

Comment: So, the "e" object : {
  "error": {
    "code": "access_denied",
    "message": "Could not get resource"
  }
}

Comment: access denied, sounds like you are not properly authorized. debug before the /me endpoint. what´s "type"? what´s in "auth"? btw, you should use typesafe comparison instead.

Comment: with console.log(auth): {
  "access_token": "EAASaYuKrZAZBEBAFOK15S2RZBF9EjlS6mN7F5vyZBpj9175DJ8OMfeogFJXlnP0D....................",
  "data_access_expiration_time": "1572860539",
  "expires_in": 4660,
  "state": "",
  "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "network": "facebook",
  "display": "popup",
  "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:81/da_site/",
  "scope": "email",
  "expires": 1565089203.49
} so is good no ?